# Flutter add class to widget built by future builder

Tags: flutter

I got great help to build this dynamic expansionTile, now I am trying to add a class that gets passed to the onTap so that it can be passed to another page. I have tried several things and keep getting this error.  If I do not add anything to the onTap other then function call all works but have no data to pass.

Any guidance would be great.

I get this error:

```
I/flutter (15773): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (15773): The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty; state:
I/flutter (15773): _FutureBuilderState#fe2cf()):
I/flutter (15773): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I/flutter (15773): This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
I/flutter (15773): process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
I/flutter (15773): only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
I/flutter (15773): builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
I/flutter (15773): Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
I/flutter (15773): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter (15773):   Overlay([LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#5da5e]; state: OverlayState#12b2d(tracking 2 tickers;
I/flutter (15773):   entries: [OverlayEntry#b3821(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#b2a00(opaque:
I/flutter (15773):   false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#a0c04(opaque: true; maintainState: false),
I/flutter (15773):   OverlayEntry#11271(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#54209(opaque: false;
I/flutter (15773):   maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#1a91b(opaque: false; maintainState: true)]))
I/flutter (15773): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
I/flutter (15773):   FutureBuilder(dirty; state: _FutureBuilderState#fe2cf())
I/flutter (15773):
```

I am trying to run this code now its under the ExpansionTile widget during the loop over the json, I add the elements to the _onTap function and also tried to just build the class and add class to _onTap and the error continues.  Without this it works fine, but I need the data on the other page.  Any ideas would be great, I am sure I am missing something stupid since I am new to flutter from other languages.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:cswauthapp/models.dart';
import 'package:cswauthapp/FacPage.dart';
import 'package:cswauthapp/ReasonPage.dart';

import 'dart:convert';


class SpecPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SpecPage({Key key, this.spec}) : super(key: key);

  final Specialties spec;

  //final Facilities fac;
  //static const String routeName = "/specs/spec";

  @override
  _SpecPageState createState() => new _SpecPageState();
}

class _SpecPageState extends State<SpecPage> {
  Future<http.Response> _responseFuture;

  bool _authenticated = false;
  bool _dataReceived = false;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  List myReasonlist;
  int listcount = 0;
  int specid;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _responseFuture = http.get('http://$baseurl:8080/support/dc/${widget.spec.id}');

    _getPrefs();
    //_getSpecialty();
    //_getFacilities();
  }

  _getPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _authenticated = prefs.getBool('authenticated');
    print('AUTH3: ' + _authenticated.toString());
    print('AUTHCODE3: ' + prefs.getString('authcode'));
    prefs.setInt('specid', widget.spec.id);
    print('SPECID: ' + prefs.getInt('specid').toString());
    specid = await prefs.getInt('specid');
    _getReasons();
  }

  var jsonCodec = const JsonCodec();

  _getReasons() async {
    var _url = 'http://$baseurl:8080/support/getreferralreasons/$specid';

    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.get(_url);

    var reasons = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);

    myReasonlist = await reasons.toList();
    //_dataReceived = true;

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _dataReceived = true;
        listcount = myReasonlist.length;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _onRefresh() {
    Completer<Null> completer = new Completer<Null>();
    Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _children = <Widget>[

      new Center(
        child: new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
          child: new Text('Referral Reasons for '+widget.spec.name,
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),

      new Expanded(
          child: new FutureBuilder(
            future: _responseFuture,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> response) {
              if (!response.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: const Text('Loading...'),
                );
              } else if (response.data.statusCode != 200) {
                return const Center(
                  child: const Text('Error loading data'),
                );
              } else {
                List<dynamic> json = JSON.decode(response.data.body);
                return new MyExpansionTileList(json);
              }
            },
          ),

      ),

      /*new Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: new RefreshIndicator(
          child: new ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
            itemCount: listcount,
          ),
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,

        ),
      ),*/

    ];
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("My Specialty")),
      body: new Column(
        children: _children,
      ),
    );
  }

  /*Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    Reasons reason = getReason(index);
    return new ReasonWidget(reason: reason,);
  }*/

  Reasons getReason(int index) {
    return new Reasons(
        myReasonlist[index]['rid'],
        myReasonlist[index]['reason'],
        myReasonlist[index]['sid'],
        myReasonlist[index]['specname']
    );
    //return new Specialties.fromMap(mylist[index]);

  }
}

class MyExpansionTileList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<dynamic> elementList;

  MyExpansionTileList(this.elementList);

  List<Widget> _getChildren() {
    List<Widget> children = [];
    elementList.forEach((element) {
      children.add(
        new MyExpansionTile(element['did'], element['dname']),
      );
    });
    return children;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView(
      children: _getChildren(),
    );
  }
}

class MyExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final int did;
  final String name;

  MyExpansionTile(this.did, this.name);
  @override
  State createState() => new MyExpansionTileState();
}

class MyExpansionTileState extends State<MyExpansionTile> {
  PageStorageKey _key;
  Future<http.Response> _responseFuture;
  List<Widget> reasonList;
  List reasList;
  //Reasons reason;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _responseFuture =
        http.get('http://$baseurl:8080/support/dcreasons/${widget.did}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _key = new PageStorageKey('${widget.did}');
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: _key,
      title: new Text(widget.name,
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        new FutureBuilder(
          future: _responseFuture,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> response) {
            if (!response.hasData) {
              return const Center(
                child: const Text('Loading...'),
              );
            } else if (response.data.statusCode != 200) {
              return const Center(
                child: const Text('Error loading data'),
              );
            } else {
              List<dynamic> json = JSON.decode(response.data.body);
              reasonList = [];
              json.forEach((element) {

                reasonList.add(new ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  title: new Text(element['reason']),
                  onTap: _onTap(new Reasons(element['rid'], element['reason'], element['sid'], element['specname'])),
                ));
              });
              //reasList = json.toList();
              return new Column(children: reasonList);
            }

          },

        )
      ],
    );
  }

  _onTap(Reasons reason) {
    Route route = new MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: new RouteSettings(name: "/reasons/reason"),
      builder: (BuildContext context) => new ReasonPage(reason: reason),
    );
    Navigator.of(context).push(route);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, not sure why, but I did the method inline and it worked.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _key = new PageStorageKey('${widget.did}');
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: _key,
      title: new Text(widget.name,
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        new FutureBuilder(
          future: _responseFuture,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> response) {
            if (!response.hasData) {
              return const Center(
                child: const Text('Loading...'),
              );
            } else if (response.data.statusCode != 200) {
              return const Center(
                child: const Text('Error loading data'),
              );
            } else {
              List<dynamic> json = JSON.decode(response.data.body);
              reasonList = [];
              json.forEach((element) {

                reasonList.add(new ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  leading: new Text(' - '),
                  title: new Text(element['reason']),
                  //HERE IS WHERE I FIXED IT.
                  onTap: () {
                    Route route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                      settings: new RouteSettings(name: "/reasons/reason"),
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => new ReasonPage(id: element['rid'], reason: element['reason'], sid: element['sid']),
                    );
                    Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                  },
                ));
              });
              //reasList = json.toList();
              return new Column(children: reasonList);
            }

          },

        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by inline?